# Trying to conditionally display div only if inside image exists

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

Basically I have a composite which is responsible for displaying an image. But this image is wrapped inside a `<picture>` tag which is wrapped inside a `<div>` tag. And what I am trying to achieve is only display the outer `<div>` if the image exists.

My approach:
At the beginning I had this:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <div class="logo-class">
        <picture>
            <p:graphicImage value="#{bean.logo}" alt="{cc.attrs.name} - #{cc.attrs.location}">
                <f:param name="key" value="#{cc.attrs.key}" />
            </p:graphicImage>
        </picture>
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

Using the following bean:

```
public StreamedContent getLogo()
{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE)
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();

    String key = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("key");
    if (key == null || key.isEmpty())
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();

    try
    {
        Document logo = logosService.read(key);
        if (logo == null)
            return new DefaultStreamedContent();

        return new ByteArrayContent(logo.getContent(), logo.getMimeType(), logo.getFilename());
    }
    catch (ValidationException ve)
    {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent();
    }
}
```

I modified my composite to look like this. Don't know if this approach is the best...

```
<c:set var="logo" value="#{bean.getLogo(cc.attrs.key)}" />

<p:outputPanel rendered="#{logo != null}" styleClass="logo-class">
    <picture>
        <p:graphicImage value="#{logo}" alt="#{cc.attrs.name} - #{cc.attrs.location}" />
    </picture>
</p:outputPanel>
```

And of course I created a new bean method:

```
public StreamedContent getLogo(String key)
{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE)
        return null;

    if (key == null || key.isEmpty())
        return null;

    try
    {
        Document logo= logosService.read(key);
        if (logo== null)
            return null;

        return new ByteArrayContent(logo.getContent(), logo.getMimeType(), logo.getFilename());
    }
    catch (ValidationException ve)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The markup structure is non-modifieble.

The problem I have is that now, no Logo image is displayed and when debugging I'm unable to reach the line `Document logo = logosService.read(key);`. I always reach the first condition `if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE)`... but then nothing more. What could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like the problem is `if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) return null;`. What is its purpose? Prevent unnecessary streams because of c:set? Just don't do the c:set.

Comment: A component's `rendered` can be evaluated many times during a single request. Better not make it that heavy. Make a special light-weight method for checking if the image exists.

Comment: Why don't do the `c:set`? I somehow need to know if the image exists before rendering the `<div>` tag... So, it would be better to make a method on the backing bean to check if the image exists? And then have a condition like this: `<p:outputPanel rendered="item.hasImage()">`, or something like that?

Comment: "Why don't do the c:set?" Ignore that part actually. c:set won't evaluate it's value immediately, so it doesn't matter. Anyway, your strange RENDER_RESPONSE check and return is the problem - p:outputPanel will not be rendered ever because of it. Yes, a specialized `hasImage` check would be more optimal performance-wise.

Comment: Ok. And what would the `hasImage()` method contain? I mean I am calling a service to read my Image and I tried something similar. I was storing the image as a `StreamedContent` directly on the backing bean and in the constructor I was setting the `StreamedContent` and xhtml looked like this: `<p:graphicImage value="#{bean.logo}" alt="Logo von #{cc.attrs.name} - #{cc.attrs.location}" />`. And the ideea is it somwhow worked because the items having no image were not displayed and the items having an image were displayed, but only the `alt` attribute was visible, not the image itself...

Comment: please comment if the answers does not moot your needs or accept the answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a property (`boolean`) in your `bean` class to tell you whether the logo is present.
2. Make use of the `fragment` function to render the `<div/>` tag.

**Example;**

Make use of the core JSF tag library `xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"`

Wrap the fragment around the `<div/>`.

```
<ui:fragment rendered="#{bean.logoPresent}">

<div class="logo-class">
        <picture>
            <p:graphicImage value="#{bean.logo}" alt="{cc.attrs.name} - #{cc.attrs.location}">
                <f:param name="key" value="#{cc.attrs.key}" />
            </p:graphicImage>
        </picture>
    </div>
</ui:fragment>
```

3. The `getLogo()` method won't be executed as the `boolean` check will prevent it.

Comment: Hello. But it will be executed twice if the logo is present. Basically to know if there is a logo (for the boolean check) a service needs to be called which returns the content, mimeType ans so on. And if it exists then it will be called once more by the `p:graphicImage`, so in the worst case scenario if I have a list with 200 items, each of them having a logo, the service will get called 400 times...

Comment: Ok, what scope is your bean? You will be able to set a Bean variable of type Boolean (Object), then set the true / false based on the first run of the logo check, when its present, you can fetch the image content. Ensure that the logo check is as lightweight as possible, if it is present, fetch the content.

Answer (score 0):

You need a logoName, a lazy initialized derived field called logo and validLogo field to flag the value in logo is validated. The validLogo field should reset to false when the bean.logoName has changed (the loading needed again).

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MyBean
{
  // Attributes
  private String logoName;

  // Derived attributes
  private boolean validLogo;
  private Document logo;

  public String getLogoName()
  {
    return logoName;
  };

  public void setLogoName( String logoName_ )
  {
    logoName = logoName_;
    validLogo = false;
  };

  public boolean isLogoExist()
  {
    if ( !validLogo )
      validateLogo();
    return logo != null;
  }

  protected void validateLogo()
  {
    // The magic takes place here to load the image into the logo field
  }

}
```

The facelet:

```
<p:outputPanel rendered="#{myBean.logoExist}" styleClass="logo-class">
  <picture>
    <p:graphicImage value="#{myBean.logo}" alt="#{cc.attrs.name} - #{cc.attrs.location}" />
  </picture>
</p:outputPanel>
```

In this case the rerendered page does not want to reload the logo from the file until the name of the logo does not change (or you does not leave the view).